# Is there an English word whose definition is the ability to tell truth from a lie?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

There doesn't seem to be an English word describing the ability to tell truth from a lie. I've Googled, and posted on my FB account, but can't seem to find a word that precisely describes this ability.

- Discernment. M-W defines this as "able to see and understand people things, or situations clearly and intelligently." Best so far, but a bit off the mark. It does not precisely identify the ability to perceive and separate truth from falsehoods.
- The antonym of gullible
- A discerning ear
- (Slang) anti-bs meter; able to discern bullsh!t.

Others have suggested guarded, prudent, realistic, astute, and perceptive... but none of these precisely describe the quality that I've described.

The word should fit 'XXXXXXX' in the following:

> John is so gullible; he'll believe anything. Not so Jane, she is XXXXXXX. She has quite the discerning ear; you'll never be able to deceive her with a lie.

Here are some possibles (consulted thesaurus.com; listed antonyms for `gullible`; definitions from Google.)

- discerning. Having or showing good judgment. Discussed above; best so far, but a bit off the mark.
- astute. Having or showing an ability to accurately assess situations or people and turn this to one's advantage. Rejected because does not account for lies.
- knowledgeable. intelligent and well informed. Does not speak to distinguishing truth from lies.
- perceptive. Having or showing sensitive insight. Does not speak to discernment of truth or lies.
- suspicious. Having or showing a cautious distrust of someone or something.. Speaks more to distrust than separation of truth from lies.
- unbelieving. Not believing someone or something. Does not speak to the ability to distinguish truth from lies.

Comment: From the title, I came here to post *discernment.* But you have already discounted it.

Comment: This question is a [tag:single-word-request] and as such needs to be edited to include a requisite contextual sentence to help us understand what the best word is to meet your needs. Since you have proposed a synonym/antonym, you should also show us that you have consulted [a thesaurus](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/thesaurus/gullible) and tell us why you have dismissed at least the very best examples as meeting your needs. The question may end up closed otherwise.

Comment: I hate this kind of question. I don't believe there exists some inherent trait or personality type that encompasses an ***ability*** to **perceive** that a lie is being told. That's a crock, as they say in my neighborhood. This is not an ability. One person could figure out if a particular person is lying in some instances, but not in others. Many factors come into play.

Comment: @Lambie,  I see your point, but the fact remains that some people are much easier to fool than others. What is the adjective to describe one that is not-so-easy-to-fool?

Comment: I could suggest **judicious** although, for my taste, it has too many other flavors concerning a person's public bearing on top of their perception in judgment.

Comment: She is a ***human lie detector***...

Comment: @Lambie  It might not be "ability" but it does come with experience in dealing with people.  Good poker players learn to notice 'tells' that many players have when they are feeling a certain way.  It isn't 'voodoo" or "ESP".. it is noticing mannerisms like when and how naturally or compulsively they wring their hands or touch their brow. There are all degrees of skill in lying too. Some nearly everybody can see through (when a person starts denying something they aren't accused of you can guess something fishy is up), and some small things you can notice by omission when you know a field.

Comment: From the title it sounds like you want a noun, "the ability", but *gullible* is an adjective. Which do you want, a noun or an adjective? In either case there seems to be no single word, just as there is no single word antonym to *lie*.

Comment: 'Not so Jane, she's a veritable lie detector' is what I'd say, metaphorically comparing her to the machine.

Answer (score 2):

How about the word wisdom?

Def: The ability to discern what is true, right, etc.
if you can discern truth then you automatically negate lies.

The use of the word discern in the definition also, in my opinion, doesn't pose a problem since it is defined as follows:
**if you discern something, you are aware of it and know it. ie the truth**

Collins dictionary.

Comment: In my mind, wisdom has that King Solomon quality about it. I don't disagree that ``wisdom`` encompasses the ability to discern truth from lie, but wisdom embodies far more. I seek a term that more precisely describes the ability to discern truth from lie. Perhaps ``discern`` is the best that English has to offer.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  Yes, perhaps wisdom is too general .

Answer (score 0):

I might suggest the word **Sagacious**

Sagacious combines some elements of "wise to the world" with the concept of a sharp and well considered use of intellect, as I understand the word

> [**Sagacious** at Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/sagacious) adjective
>
> 1.
>   having or showing acute mental discernment and keen practical sense; shrewd:
>
> *a sagacious lawyer.*

Comment: 'Discerning' which is really your best choice, @kmiklas (because it connotes the ability to *discern* a truth from a lie) is also used to define 'sagacious' in this excellent answer and therefore 'sagacious' is another good option that fits your case.

Answer (score 0):

> There doesn't seem to be an English word describing the ability to tell truth from a lie.

That is because English is an excellent language that realises that the ability to tell truth from a lie 100% of the time does not exist.

As a consequence, any antonym for gullible, which does **not** mean "always accepts a lie as the truth" is not going to encompass this idea of infallibility.

The nearest you will get is a reasonable approximation:

OED

**streetwise,** adj.

**Of a person: that has the skills and knowledge necessary for dealing with modern urban life; smart; tough. Of a thing: suitable for or reflective of modern urban life.**

1949   P. W. Tappan Juvenile Delinquency xix. 538   *She was streetwise enough not to get involved in the same area twice.*

**Canny**

**c. Cautious and careful in worldly or business matters; worldly-wise, shrewd.**

1987   P. Wright & P. Greengrass Spycatcher vi. 73   *In fact, the intelligence gathered was worthless. Khrushchev was far too canny a bird to discuss anything of value in a hotel room.*

**astute**, adj.

**Of keen penetration or discernment, esp. in regard to one's own interests; shrewd, subtle, sagacious; wily, cunning, crafty.**

1878   R. B. Smith Carthage 331   *He had, with the astute fickleness of a barbarian, come to a secret understanding with Scipio.*

You will note that within the above definitions there are other close synonyms that you may find useful.